# Broadcasting ranges

Tags: arrays, julia, array-broadcasting

I have an array of arrays in my dataframe - `split.(df2.name)`:

```
> 392-element Array{Array{SubString{String},1},1}:
 ["chevrolet", "chevelle", "malibu"]
 ["buick", "skylark", "320"]        
 ["plymouth", "satellite"]          
 ["amc", "rebel", "sst"]            
 ["ford", "torino"]                 
 ⋮                                  
 ["ford", "mustang", "gl"]          
 ["vw", "pickup"]                   
 ["dodge", "rampage"]               
 ["ford", "ranger"]                 
 ["chevy", "s-10"]
```

I want to select all but the first element of each array and join them together, to get the model names of these cars.

First, I thought to do something like this: `model = join.(split.(df2.name)[2:end], " ")`   but instead of removing the first element of each array, this removes the first car (The first element of the outer array).

So I thought to broadcast the range `[2:end]` to all the elements by puting a point just before the range: `model = join.(split.(df2.name).[2:end], " ")`. But this does not seem to work either, because there is a syntax error:

```
syntax: missing last argument in "2:" range expression
```

So what is the julian way to broadcast a range in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a little tricky to use a plain broadcast here since, as you found out, building the `2:end` range explicitly results in a syntax error. I think this is because expressions like

```
a[2:end]
```

are specially parsed and lowered to something like

```
a[2:lastindex(a)]
```

as explained in the documentation for [`lastindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.lastindex).

You can however use an iterator like `Iterators.drop` in order to iterate through all elements but the first, an operation which can be broadcasted:

```
julia> cars = [["chevrolet", "chevelle", "malibu"],
               ["buick", "skylark", "320"],        
               ["plymouth", "satellite"],          
               ["amc", "rebel", "sst"],            
               ["ford", "torino"]];

julia>  join.(Iterators.drop.(cars, 1), " ")
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "chevelle malibu"
 "skylark 320"
 "satellite"
 "rebel sst"
 "torino"
```

But I think that in this case, I would probably go for a comprehension, which I think would be more readable:

```
julia> [join(car[2:end], " ") for car in cars]
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "chevelle malibu"
 "skylark 320"
 "satellite"
 "rebel sst"
 "torino"
```

---

**EDIT:** looking back at your global problem, it looks like you first `split` more than you want, then struggle `join`ing back the parts you didn't want to split in the first place.

So you might want to take advantage of the `limit` keyword argument to [`split`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.split), so that you dont split too many words in the first place:

```
julia> cars2 = ["chevrolet chevelle malibu",
                "buick skylark 320",
                "plymouth satellite",
                "amc rebel sst",
                "ford torino"];

julia> split.(cars2, " ", limit=2)
5-element Array{Array{SubString{String},1},1}:
 ["chevrolet", "chevelle malibu"]
 ["buick", "skylark 320"]
 ["plymouth", "satellite"]
 ["amc", "rebel sst"]
 ["ford", "torino"]

julia> getindex.(split.(cars2, " ", limit=2), 2)
5-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "chevelle malibu"
 "skylark 320"
 "satellite"
 "rebel sst"
 "torino"
```

This last example also demonstrates how to broadcast indexing syntax via the explicit `getindex(a, i)` function call, which is the lowered form of syntactic sugar `a[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, broadcasting indexing syntax works by converting it to `getindex` and broadcasting that:

```
model = join.(getindex.(split.(df2.name), Ref(2:10)), " ")
```

`Ref` is needed to treat the range as a scalar; you can also use a 1-tuple instead.

That's the easy part.  However, this trick becomes ugly to use with `end`, since outside of the brackets it has no meaning, which is the reasone for the error you got.  One way to resolve the problem is to replace `end` with `lastindex`, but then you should probably cache the array calculation:

```
model = let nameparts = split.(df2.name)
    join.(getindex.(nameparts, Ref(2:lastindex(nameparts))), " ")
end
```

This loses the advantage of the broadcast fusion, though.

In this specific case, you could also use `Iterators.rest`, since we know about how `Array` iterators work:

```
join.(Iterators.rest.(split.(df2.name), 2), " ")
```

But the easiest version in my opinion is just a comprehension:

```
model = [join(split(carname)[2:end]) for carname in df2.name]
```

(Unless you're very familiar with `Iterators`.  Then I'd personally prefer the previous one.)